# Listing all Yum repos without internet access

Tags: centos, yum, repository

With my enterprise, we are looking to block full internet access to the linux servers.
Without internet, I cannot do for example: `yum -v repolist all`

I am trying to get every URL from `/etc/yum/repolist.d`
with `grep -Eoh "(http)://[a-z^CZ0-9./?=_%:-]*" /etc/yum.repos.d/*` or even if a basic *grep http|https*

I finally tried to whitelist this URL list obtained from the grep's result:

```
http://blog.remirepo.net
http://cdn.remirepo.net
http://debuginfo.centos.org
http://download.example
http://forum.remirepo.net
http://mirror.centos.org
http://mirrorlist.centos.org
http://rpms.remirepo.net
https://artifacts.elastic.co
https://blog.remirepo.net
https://download.webmin.com
https://forum.remirepo.net
https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org
https://rpms.remirepo.net
http://vault.centos.org
http://yum.centreon.com
```

After that, when I try to use `yum update` or `yum install something`, we see URL/mirrors not present in `/etc/yum/repolist.d`.

```
http://ftp.rezopole.net/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/repodata/a4e2b46586aa556c3b6f814dad5b16db5a669984d66b68e873586cd7c7253301-c7-x86_64-comps.xml.gz: <br/>[Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2a03:9180:1:20::29: Network is unreachable"
Essai d'un autre miroir.
epel/x86_64/group_gz           FAILED
```

Where can I find this information in CentOS?

> ftp.rezopole.net

Comment: You can set the mirrors in exclusion list from there https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/

Comment: You're using mirror lists and there is probably a bunch of data stored in your yum cache.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the way to go would be to uncomment all the baseurl= and to comment every mirrorlist= ?